# Links dinâmicos com parâmetros

Tags: php, url

Olá!

Estou com uma dúvida. Gostaria de criar um arquivo externo ao menu de um site que fique responsável por fazer o link entre as páginas, mas estou com muita dificuldade na execução. Estou começando com PHP agora...

Por exemplo:

Meu menu tem:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="./r.php?codigo=0" id="hl">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="./r.php?codigo=1" id="hl">Quem Somos</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="./r.php?codigo=2" id="hl">Textos</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="./r.php?codigo=3" id="hl">Contato</a>
```

No arquivo r.php estou usando a superglobal $_GET para pegar essa informação:

```
<?php
 $link = $_GET['codigo'];
 $endereco = array("./index.php","./quemsomos/index.php","./textos/index.php","./contato/index.php");

 header('location: ' . $endereco[$link]);
?>
```

O primeiro funciona, porque o arquivo r.php está na pasta raíz, junto do primeiro index.php. Já os outros não encontram o arquivo e estou com dificuldade para fazê-lo.

Tinha lido que o './' faz a busca a partir da pasta raíz da aplicação, mas não está funcionando. Alguma dica?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de criar index.php dentro de várias pastas você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:
Deixe um arquivo `index.php` na raiz e dentro desse arquivo coloque o seu **menu**.

Crie na raiz uma pasta com o nome "**paginas**".
Dentro dessa pasta crie os arquivos: `home.php` , `quemsomos.php` , `textos.php` , `contato.php`

Então, ainda na raiz, crie um arquivo chamado `paginacao.php`
Dentro desse arquivo escreva o seguinte código:

```
<?php

switch ($_GET['codigo']) {

    case '0':
        $conteudo = "home.php";
    break;

    case '1':
        $conteudo = "paginas/quemsomos.php";
    break;

    case '2':
        $conteudo = "paginas/textos.php";
    break;

    case '3':
        $conteudo = "paginas/contato.php";
    break;

    default:
        $conteudo = "home.php";
    break;
}

?>
```

Volta na página `index.php` da raíz e coloque o seguinte código após o seu **menu**:

```
<?php 

    include("paginacao.php");
    include($conteudo);
?>
```

Comment: Andei pesquisando e fiz algo parecido com isso. E outra, incrementei essa mesma lógica numa página que mostra dinamicamente os textos/postagens. Obrigado pela ajuda!